# Convert Tensor to numpy array in TF 2.x

Tags: numpy, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to load [Universal Sentence Encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/5) and this is my code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import os, requests, tarfile

def extractUSEEmbeddings(words):
    # Extracts USE embeddings
    # Replace `USE_folder` with any directory in your machine, where you want USE to be downloaded
    try:
        embed = hub.KerasLayer(USE_folder)
    except Exception as e:
        print ("Downloading USE embeddings...")
        r = requests.get("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5?tf-hub-format=compressed")
        open("USE.tar.gz", "wb").write(r.content)
        
        tar = tarfile.open("USE.tar.gz", "r:gz")
        tar.extractall(path=USE_folder)
        tar.close()

        os.remove("USE.tar.gz")
        embed = hub.KerasLayer(USE_folder)
        pass
    word_embeddings = embed(words)
    return word_embeddings.numpy()
```

I get the error `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`. When I run the same code on Jupyter notebook, with the same versions of `tensorflow` (2.2.0) and `tensorflow-hub` (0.9.0), I do not get any error and it works perfectly fine.

I printed the `type` of Tensor in both cases, and realized that this is because I get an `Eager Tensor` (`tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor`) in Jupyter, which has a `numpy` method whereas in my script, the `Tensor` is of type `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor`. However, I am now unable to figure out how to switch on Eager Execution in my script, since in TF 2.x it is supposed to be enabled by default.

I have tried all the solutions given in [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27519), but none of them work for me.

Why am I not getting an Eager Tensor when run through the terminal, but get it through Jupyter? Does my problem have anything to do with the fact that I am using `tensorflow-hub` here, and is that why none of the solutions are working for me? Most importantly, how do I convert `Tensor` in tf 2.x to a `numpy` array?

Comment: What is `words`? If that's an EagerTensor, `word_embeddings` should be as well, but if it's a symbolic Tensor, like what you'd get from tf.keras.layers.Input, then this carries over. (This has nothing to do with tensorflow_hub per se and applies to any other Keras layer as well.)

Comment: `words` is a Python list of English words/phrases/sentences, for which we are extracting embeddings. eg. ["horse", "river", "my house"]

Comment: Can't tell; your code works for me. Be sure to not call `tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()` or `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` anywhere else in your Python program. --- BTW, please see https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/caching on how to avoid the tedious manual unpacking.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Strange, I have not called either of those functions anywhere. Are you sure you ran it from the terminal and not on a Jupyter notebook? Because it works on Jupyter for me as well

Comment: To convert a tensor into numpy array in tf2.x, please follow link :- https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray